# Android:How do I change Action Bar Title Depending on the value of selected Item

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have android application where I want the title of action bar to change in according to the selected entity. To provide more details Screen 1 has a list of entities. On Click event of that entity , redirects to another activity which should display the action bar title according to the entity selected. What is the best approach to achieve the above mentioned functionality

Answer (score 1):

there is a single method 
getActionBar().setTitle("WRITE YOUR TITLE HERE");
in onCreate() method of Your Activity and Your answer will be solved

Answer (score 1):

In your Androidmanifest.xml file you can use the android:label for setting the default actionbar title for that specific activity. Here is an example:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="1" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActiv"
        android:label="2"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.aaa.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```